# Do I have to mention OP of a GitHub project issue?

Tags: github

Do I have to mention her so she would receive a notification?

The official sources,

- https://guides.github.com/features/issues/#notifications
- https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/#GitHub-flavored-markdown

are not helping.

This one, http://ben.balter.com/2014/11/06/rules-of-communicating-at-github/, says -

> OP will eventually take the hint.

But does that mean she will be notified only if her team is cc'ed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you get notifications on any issues you create:

> You’re receiving notifications because you authored the thread.

However this can be turned off if OP hits the <kbd>Unsubscribe</kbd> button. So
if you want to be safe, mention OP in your comment.

Keep in mind that if OP is unsubscribed, they did it for a reason. Follow good
etiquette and avoid overusing `@` mentions.